# Estoy obteniendo java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, json, api

Hola por acá realizando nuevas consultas.

Estoy avanzando en un proyecto *API REST* en Java estoy obteniendo el siguiente error al querer mostrar mis sucursales de una base relacionada donde sucursales es el padre.

> ```
> Error al mostrar la sucursal java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You
> have attempted to set a parameter at position 1 which does not exist
> in this query string SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.id = :id.
> ```

### SucursalesREST

```
@Path("/sucursales")
public class SucursalesREST {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UP_Sucursales");
    EntityManager em;
@GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response buscarsucursal(@PathParam("id") int  id) {
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();

            Sucursal sucursal = em.find(Sucursal.class, id);
            sucursal.setEmpleadoList(em.createNamedQuery("Sucursal.findById").setParameter(id , sucursal).getResultList());

            System.out.println(sucursal.getEmpleadoList());

            return Response.ok(sucursal.toJSON()).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.ok(500).entity("Error al mostrar la sucursal " + e).build();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
```

Mis archivos de persistencia:

### Sucursal

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package root.persistence.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author rodrigo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "sucursales")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findByComuna", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.comuna = :comuna")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Sucursal.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT s FROM Sucursal s WHERE s.direccion = :direccion")})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope=Sucursal.class)
public class Sucursal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "comuna")
    private String comuna;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idsucursal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Empleado> empleadoList;

    public Sucursal() {
    }

    public Sucursal(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getComuna() {
        return comuna;
    }

    public void setComuna(String comuna) {
        this.comuna = comuna;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Empleado> getEmpleadoList() {
        return empleadoList;
    }

    public void setEmpleadoList(List<Empleado> empleadoList) {
        this.empleadoList = empleadoList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Sucursal)) {
            return false;
        }
        Sucursal other = (Sucursal) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "root.persistence.entities.Sucursal[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public Object toJSON() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

### Empleado

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package root.persistence.entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author rodrigo
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "empleados")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByNombre", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByApellido", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.apellido = :apellido")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByRut", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.rut = :rut")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByPuesto", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.puesto = :puesto")})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope=Empleado.class)
public class Empleado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "rut")
    private String rut;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "puesto")
    private String puesto;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idsucursal", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Sucursal idsucursal;

    public Empleado() {
    }

    public Empleado(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getRut() {
        return rut;
    }

    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {
        return puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }

    public Sucursal getIdsucursal() {
        return idsucursal;
    }

    public void setIdsucursal(Sucursal idsucursal) {
        this.idsucursal = idsucursal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Empleado)) {
            return false;
        }
        Empleado other = (Empleado) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "root.persistence.entities.Empleado[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

No sé en qué me estoy equivocando, ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme.